# MVC prevent reauthentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, owin, access-token

I have an issue which plays out as follows:

When my users use my MVC app, they keep a particular page open most of the time as it is for logging phone calls. So the logging screen remains open, they then take a call and enter all the information, and then submit, but then if there was a fair gap between phone calls, then the token expires and they need to reauthenticate which redirects them to microsoftonline which then loses the data they had input.

Therefore is there any way to either prevent the reauthentication so that the controller can be accessed or perform a token refresh before the submit is performed in order for it to go through authenticated.

Im not sure what information will be of help to solve this so if i can provide any snippets etc to help please say and ill upload them immediately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Set a custom session duration for your app's session cookies: to do this, you'll need to ensure that OWIN is not overwriting the session cookie lifetime (see link below for how to use `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` to do this).
2. Add session renewing logic to your app: one way to do this is with an `iframe` a route in your app that generates an authorization request.

Vittorio goes into this in detail in his blog post: [Controlling a Web App's session duration](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/07/25/controlling-a-web-apps-session-duration-2/).

Comment: I have just tried to implement this iframe solution as it seemed the better, however, it doesnt seem to like me using `document` and `console` in the layout.cshtml. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. What exactly is the issue you are facing?

Comment: `The name document does not exist in the current context` when placing the setInterval snippet from the page you linked, into my layout.cshtml.

Comment: ah apologies i must have removed the <text> tag inadvertently. i will test this now

Comment: Do you know a way to store the timer value in a cookie or similar when you navigate away from a page and then retrieve it and start the timer from that point upon page load. currently it does not perform the reauthentication all of the time as the timer is reset upon page load